# What is the bbdb3 field "affix" used for?

Tags: bbdb

Does it work for a job title or is it used for academic titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it does not have a well defined meaning, from the [bbdb mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/bbdb/mailman/message/31729494/)

> So far, the affix field in BBDB 3 **does not have a detailed meaning**.
>   Its value is a list of strings.  So I guess it can stand for all kinds
>   of prefixes, suffixes, academic titles, and what else.  But depending
>   on a user's cultural background, the details may vary quite a bit what
>   he or she wants to store in this field and I don't know whether it
>   would make much sense if BBDB tried to establish some universal rules
>   here.

Answer (score 2):

**Application**

The affix field looks like the following: The affix entry `Dr.`is put behind the name (separated by a comma) and before the slash `-` before the organisation entry.  I guess the reason it was called "affix" is that depending on the culture, entries - for example for academic titles - can be written as prefixes or suffixes.

[image: bbdb3 affix example]